# Running a single callback on multiple jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

```
$('#one, #two').animate({opacity: 100}, function() {
  console.log($.now());
});
```

Because this code has 2 selectors the callback runs twice. Is there a way to make it only run once?

Comment: do you want to include the same selector for 2 items ?

Comment: `opacity` goes from `0` to `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a complete callback, you can use [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [`deferred.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) to wait for the animation queue to be finished.

```
$('#one, #two').animate({opacity: 1}).promise().then(function() {
  console.log($.now());
});
```

Note that the promise will resolve when the entire queue has finished, so if you queue additional animations before the first animation has completed you will need to use a different technique.